# Does it make sense to calculate odds ratio for a continuous outcome?

Tags: r, regression, odds-ratio

I seemed to be confused about what to report for a logistic regression analysis.
My outcome variable is continuous (ie, test scores), while my predictor is continuous (ie, blood pressure), and confounding variables are binary or continuous (ie, age, gender, years of education, presence of stroke).

I have been reporting Beta estimates (standard error), and p-values (for the unadjusted, and adjusted models when controlling for confounding variables), because from what I understand, those are the values that are usually reported if the outcome is continuous. On the other hand, odds ratio (95%CI) are reported for binary outcomes.

I think my confusion about whether I should be reporting beta estimates (SE) or odds ratio (95%CI) for the variables mentioned above is because I've been reading research articles that seem to report things differently with similar kinds of variables that I have.

It doesn't seem to make sense to calculate odds ratio with a continuous outcome, right?

Thanks everyone who can help me out with this!

```
glm(formula = global ~ AC + Age + gender + education, data = data)  
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -2.53917    1.61381  -1.573   0.1168    
AC           1.03971    0.45302   2.295   0.0225 *  
Age         -0.03475    0.01953  -1.779   0.0764 .  
gender2      0.05652    0.27176   0.208   0.8354    
education    0.27009    0.02642  10.224   <2e-16 ***
```

Comment: It's hard to pinpoint exactly what your confusion is. I think your confusion may stem from what you are calling "beta estimates". Both linear regression (OLS) and logistic regression (LR) produce "beta estimates". However for OLS the beta is a slope and for LR the beta is a log odds ratio. Only for LR do you have to exponentiate the beta to obtain the OR. Is this correct?

Comment: @AdamOYes, I think you're right about the confusion with beta estimate. Here's just an example of my output in R above. The outcome "global" is continuous. Should i be reporting B(SE) or exponentiation beta to OR?

Comment: You only get ORs from logistic regression after exponentiating the coefficients. ORs only make sense for a binary outcome. Your outcome is continuous. Do not exponentiate the coefficients. You can call them "mean differences" instead of "odds ratios".